# Full mess on VLC after fresh installation - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, vlc

I just re-install my Ubuntu 14.04 from scratch and I'm facing troubles with VLC.
I read carrefully  [How to play multiple instances of VLC](http://goo.gl/JBIR38)

When I try to open one file it sometimes works bur when I try to open list of VLC file "*xspf*" I do note have anything on the screen.

Help would be gratefully appreciated.

Laurent06000

Comment: I even have to kill the vlc process that does not close by normal program Please help

Comment: Some files are read correctly some not . I'm losing my latin and time. please help !!!

Comment: To be complete in the description of te problem tha clc process remains active after closed and I have to kill it. Any way to help me ?

Comment: Even a de-install re-install process of VLC does NOT do ANYTHING. I remember of a link treating this special problem but cannot find it now.

Comment: This link http://goo.gl/6ZjwwR does not help either.

Comment: Neither this found in my searches : http://goo.gl/Kng47T

Comment: Video Files are correctly viewed  both by smplayer and standard  Videos player. I do hope that will help me someone to give me a hand on that problem. Laurent06000

Comment: I already read http://goo.gl/JBIR38 and applied the changes without positive changes. I just re-installed UBuntu from scratch an VLC not playing !!!!!!! I'm a bit fed up.....

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. To be sincere I do not remember the internet link where to find this answer.

In .config/vlc just put those 2 files :

vlc-qt-interface.conf :
 [vlc-qt-interface.conf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4t74ghmk7wdzps0/vlc-qt-interface.conf?dl=0)

Then in the file named vlcrc copy the following :

[vlcrc file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f27apeedl2b9dhz/vlcrc?dl=0)

===>**SAVE those two files to the .config/vlc folder and enjoy**

PS : I hope the files will be accessible  : I've made a link from personal dropbox files (please tell me if you cannot have access those 2 files too large to copy contents here....